# Efficiently adapt a python list according to another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I could not come up with a better title for my question, sorry.

I have two lists of the same length, e.g.

```
a = [True, False, False, True, True, False, False, True]
b = [1,    2,     2,     1,    1,    3,     3,     2   ]
           i      j                  i'     j'
```

I want to adjust list `a` in such a way that whenever there is a block of or a single `False` in list `a` going from index `i` to `j`, it is adjusted according to the following condition:

```
if b[i-1]==b[j+1]:
    a[i:j+1]=[True]*(j-i+1)
```

in the above example there are two such blocks: `i,j=1,2` and `i',j'=5,6`.
The result should be:

```
a = [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True]
```

I wrote a solution with a `for` loop using `if`s but that is too slow since I want to use it on very large lists.

```
a = [True, False, False, True, True, False, False, True]
b = [1,    2,     2,     1,    1,    3,     3,     2   ]

#Edit: the next two lines were originally and wrongly inside the for loop
moving=True
istart=1
for i,trp in enumerate((a)):
    if trp==False:
        if moving==False:
            # if this condition holds, the particle just started a new move
            istart = i
            moving = True
    else:
        if moving==True:
            # is this condition holds, the particle has stopped its move
            moving = False
            if b[i]==b[istart-1]:
                # if this holds, a needs to be adjusted
                a[istart:i]=[True]*(i-istart)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (The comments and variable names are like that since it's for analyzing a physics simulations)

Comment: There’s nothing that shouts “inefficient” in your code. If by “very large” lists, do you mean millions or billions of items? If so, you’re probably best off either 1) using a library (built in or third party) that can help you do some of this in C code, which will be faster. `itertools` might work. 2) rewriting this in a compiled language, such as C, C++, or Java. Plain Python is inherently slower than these languages, and writing a small chunk of code might fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. By very large I mean on the order of 10**8, but I guess it really should not be so slow... I'll definitely check out itertools

Comment: You were right dantiston. It was apparently a problem with jupyter notebook. I restarted the kernel, ran the function again and now it only takes a few seconds. I'll leave the question since Ajax1234 answered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
a = [True, False, False, True, True, False, False, True]
b = [1,    2,     2,     1,    1,    3,     3,     2   ]
new_a = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(zip(a, b), key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_list = list(itertools.chain(*[[True]*len(b) if not a and new_a[i-1][-1][-1] == new_a[i+1][-1][-1] and i > 0 else [c for c, d in b] for i, [a, b] in enumerate(new_a)]))
```

Output:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True]
```

Edit: test with new input:

```
a = [True, False, True]
b = [1, 3, 1]
new_a = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(zip(a, b), key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_list = list(itertools.chain(*[[True]*len(b) if not a and new_a[i-1][-1][-1] == new_a[i+1][-1][-1] and i > 0 else [c for c, d in b] for i, [a, b] in enumerate(new_a)]))
```

Output:

```
[True, True, True]
```

Code explanation:

`itertools.groupby` forms the consecutive blocks of `True`/`False` values into single lists. Then, `final_list` stores the result of iterating over the lists stored in `new_a`, creating a new sublist of `True` values if the sublist is composed entirely of `False` values if and only if the preceding and following values are the same. This is determined by using `enumerate` to garner the current index for each iteration. That index can then be used to access the preceding and following values via `i-1`, `i+1`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tested your code but it does not lead to the correct result. It seems to miss the pattern `[True, False, True]`, when it should become `[True, True, True]`. By the way, I found a mistake in my code which I included in the question

Comment: @Johann this answer assumes that when "there is a block of `False`" you are referring to more than one occurrence of `False`. In this case, do you mean that there can be only one instance of `False`?

Comment: Yeah that was a bad wording I guess, sorry. A single instance of `False` should also be replaced, if the pattern applies

Comment: @Johann no problem. Please see my recent edit, as I added your new input my new solution.

Comment: Your version is about three times quicker than my version. Now I just need to understand your code somehow :)

Comment: @Johann My apologies for not being clear. Please see my recent edit.